# How to disable the minor ticks in d3 log scale?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, axes

I have my real time d3 log scale graph like below:

[image: my real time log scale graph]

I would like to show only the major ticks with their labels : 10^-2, 10^-1, 10^0, 10^1, 10^2

but **not the minor ticks**

I would like to have the log Y axis look like this without the minor ticks:

[image]

How can I do this?

**EDIT:** post some code

```
svg = d3.select("#chart1").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

y = d3.scale.log().domain([1e-1, 1e2]).range([height, 0]);

yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

svg.selectAll("g.y.axis")
.call(yAxis)    
.selectAll(".tick text")
.text(null)
.filter(powerOfTen)
.text(10)
.append("tspan")
.attr("dy", "-.7em")
.text(function(d) { return Math.round(Math.log(d) / Math.LN10); });
```

You might also interested to know how to get the custom label of powerOfTen. If so, you might need to refer [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6738229)

**EDIT:** You can edit my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/WNwJr/10/)

Comment: Specify the ticks explicitly with `.tickValues()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suggested by  Lars Kotthoff

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).tickSize(0).tickValues([1e-1,1e0,1e1,1e2]).orient("left");
```

this answer force the `label`, but the `major tick` is not drawn.....

Comment: This solution doesn't scale well. If the data is lets say around 1e4, ticks will be missing.

Comment: you can always update the `tickValue` in every loop based on your push data max. But I still waiting for other more handy answer